# c# get data of json script

Tags: c#, html, json

I want to get some data of a homepage but the wanted value is in a json script. How do I get the value?

example:

```
<div id="contentWrap">
      <div id="contentTextWrap">
        <div id="contentText">
    <h1>Tiefgarage Alte Oper</h1>
      <div class="parkhaus-detail-freespaces">
    <h4>Freie Parkplätze: <span class="parkhaus-detail-freespaces-value"></span></h4>
    <em class="parkhaus-detail-freespaces-date-time"></em>
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>
```

(... later on the html script...)

```
<script>
  $.getJSON('/_extern/mdm_import/PBG/_extern/mdm_import/2781002/18944.json', function(data) {
    $('.parkhaus-detail-freespaces-value').html(data['freespaces']);
    var m = moment(data['parking_facility_status_time']);
    $('.parkhaus-detail-freespaces-date-time').html('Stand vom '+m.format('DD.MM.YYYY')+' um '+m.format('HH:mm'));
    $('.parkhaus-detail-freespaces').css('display', 'block');
  });
</script>
```

In c# I download the html-string with the webcliend, but how do I get access to the value "parkhaus-detail-freespaces-value"?

Comment: Are you using the NewtonSoft libraries for parsing the JSON client-side?

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.parse() to convert the JSON to an object, then use the object's properties

```
var artikel = JSON.parse(data); 
$('.parkhaus-detail-freespaces-value').html(artikel.freespac‌​es);
```